# I get in Visual Studio C++ these errors: 'NuovoUtente': undeclared identifier and 'CercareUtente': undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, undeclared-identifier

I get in Visual Studio C++ these errors: 'NuovoUtente': undeclared identifier and  'CercareUtente': undeclared identifier

Please answer if you now why i get these errors.

This is my Code:

[image: Code]

Comment: instead of images, post your code here

Comment: you have to declare each variable before you could use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those errors look reasonable because you never defined those values anywhere in your program. From your program, it looks like you're trying to have the user enter a string and then check whether they entered a specific piece of text, but right now you're reading in a *number* and then comparing it against a nonexistent variable. Did you mean something like this?

```
string input;
getline(cin, input);

if (input == "NuovoUtente") { // Note the == and the quotation marks
    ...
} else if (input == "CercareUtente") {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Which library is getline and input containing?

Comment: It's in the `<string>` header. If you haven't seen them before, I'd recommend picking up a good tutorial on the language.